# Cloud Firestore difference get between Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have noticed there is a difference when I call the code below between Andoid and IOS :

```
  Future getData() async{
    return await kioskCollection.document(uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      return ds.data;
});
```

When I print this :
In Android--> test:[{b:B, a:A}]
In IOS--> test:[{a:A, b:B}]

I want to uniform the result to return in Android and IOS test:[{a:A, b:B}]. How I can do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not depend on the order that Map fields are displayed when you print them out.  This is especially true for Firestore document fields, which have no defined ordering.  The Firebase console always displays them alphabetically, but that's just for display purposes.  They are not actually ordered.

If you want impose your own ordering on them, you could sort the fields alphabetically before printing them just like the console, or using some other order you choose.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is a `HashMap` which is unordered. That means the order of the values are not guaranteed.

But it shouldn't be a problem, this is a map not a list.

Comment: Thank you for the answer